# Android: Intent call from Async threw NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent, asynchronous, nullpointerexception

I Have a Activity class **FileDownloader** with AsyncTask subclass **FileDownloaderAsync**.
To update my MainActivity-ProgressDialog i want to send an intent in the **updateProgress**-function, which is called by the **onProgressUpdate**-Event.

But i get everytime a *java.lang.NullPointerException* if **Intent in = new Intent(this, ActMain.class);** is called.

Here a snippet for my code:

```
public class FileDownloader extends Activity {

...

public void updateProgress(int progressVal) {
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
    bdl.putInt("DownloadProgress", progressVal);
    Intent in = new Intent(this, ActMain.class);
    in.putExtras(bdl);
    startActivity(in);
}

    class FileDownloaderAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        ...

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress){
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", progress[0]);          
        updateProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }   

    }
}
```

And here also the Logcat-Output:

```
`02-16 10:29:52.255: W/dalvikvm(540): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)    
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3004)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at de.tachoron.lwplayer.FileDownloader.updateProgress(FileDownloader.java:40)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at de.tachoron.lwplayer.FileDownloader$FileDownloaderAsync.onProgressUpdate(FileDownloader.java:94)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at de.tachoron.lwplayer.FileDownloader$FileDownloaderAsync.onProgressUpdate(FileDownloader.java:1)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:618)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-16 10:29:52.265: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)´
```

Comment: you put an intent inside FileDownloader Activity to start the Activity FileDownloader? Why?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I tried something with the parameters and copied the wrong snipped then. But the error occured also with the fixed snippet code.

Comment: Post the error message displayed on your LogCat, the NullPointerException will be raised inside ActMain.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a wrong approach to update mainactivity progressBar. At first i am going to explain why u r getting null pointer, then i am going to show u a way which i have implemented in my project.

**NullPointer issue:**

your `updateProgress` is called several times from `onProgressUpdate`. now, when the first time progressUpdated, the `updateProgress` is called for the first time from `onProgressUpdate`. that means `startActivity(in);` is being executed in `updateProgress` and `ActMain` is started. so, at this point your `FileDownloader` activity is in `pause` state. so, when the next time progress is updated, your `updateProgress` is again called from `onProgressUpdate` and `updateProgress` tried to start `ActMain` activity using `FileDownloader's context`. but your `FileDownloader` is in pause state, that's why u r getting nullPointer exception.

**A way to update mainActivity progressBar:**

It is best way to use `BroadCast`. Don't worry, it is not complex. do exactly i have shown bellow:

in your `FileDownloader` class add these code to notify `MainActivity` about the progress change. when the download start, start your `MainActivity`.

```
public static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_ON_GOING = "downloading";
public static final String PROGRESS = "progress";
public static final String ACTION_DOWNLOADMANEGAR = "signeture_of_downloadmanegar";
public static final String ACTION_HINT = "hint";

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {                
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);             
    // Broadcast the download progress to MainActivity
    broadCast(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_ON_GOING, values[0]);
}

private void broadCast(String hint, int proggress){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(ACTION_DOWNLOADMANEGAR);
    i.putExtra(ACTION_HINT, hint);
    i.putExtra(PROGRESS, proggress);
    sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

this part of code will broadcast the progress(int) like the FM Radio station. All you have to do is, just catch the progress from another class just like our radio receive the transmission from the radio station. to receive do:

**1. Create a inner class in your MainActivity:**

```
class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        //Log.e("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);
        if (action.equals(FileDownloader.ACTION_DOWNLOADMANEGAR)) {
            String hint = intent.getStringExtra(FileDownloader.ACTION_HINT);
            if (hint.equals(FileDownloader.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_ON_GOING)) {
                //update your progrerssBar
                progressBar.setProgress(intent.getIntExtra(FileDownloader.PROGRESS, 0));
                // Log.e("Receiver", "progress: " + intent.getIntExtra(FileDownloader.PROGRESS, 0));
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

**Follow the steps:**

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
private boolean isRegistered = false;

@override
onPause(){
    supre.onPause();
    if(isRegistered){
        try {
            // use only one between the two options bellow
            // if u r using activity
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
            // if u r using Fragment
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!isRegistered){          
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(FileDownloader.ACTION_DOWNLOADMANEGAR);
        // use only one between the two options bellow
        // if u r using activity
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
        // if u r using Fragment
        getActivity().registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
        isRegistered = true;
    }
}
```

this procedure means, if u nevigate to `MainActiviy` and the download is on progress, then the progress bar in `MainActivity` will be get updated each thime the download progress is changed in your `FileDownloader`.

Let me know if u fetch any problem to implement the above procedure.

Comment: Thanks for this enourmous detailed answer! You do not only helped me with this at my current problem - you also gave me a new understanding. Thanks for your time dude! :)